# Creating a custom theme with drupal

Tags: drupal-8

I am learning drupal and want to create a custom theme for my project. I followed the instructions and created the project structure

**iseed.info.yml**

```
name: iSEED
type: theme
description: 'Learn to build a drupal theme'
package: Core
# version: VERSION
base theme: false

# Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2020-06-03
version: '1.0.0'
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
project: 'drupal'
libraries:
  - iseed/app-styling
  - iseed/app-scripts
```

**iseed.libraries.yml**

```
app-styling:
  version: 2.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/app.css: {}
app-scripts:
  version: 2.x
  js: 
    js/app.js: {}
```

**css/app.css**

```
body{
    background: red;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**css/app.js**

```
console.log("hellow owrd")
```

I dont see any change in my browser. I tried to toggle background color between red and black, to capture the updated file, but i dont see any change.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the appearance page at the path '/admin/appearance'.
After you have cleared the cache your custom theme should be visible here. Select it and set it as default.